# Why my website built in WAMP system installed in a vmware virtual machine on a vps does not redirect to right address?

Tags: redirect, vmware, wampserver, vps

I installed WAMP in a vmware virtual machine in a vps. When i digit the vps ip address i can see my home page. I log in and in my second page i cannot see the images and the relative and absolute links does not work!

I know that vmware maps:

```
  vps ip address:port  =  vmware ip address:port.
```

and i i thought that once i found the homepage with the vps ip address should be find all pages and all images!

Last but not least. if I digit vps ip address from my pc where i have stored all the files i can see all because the php pages redirect to localhost or 127.0.0.1.

How can i solve it?
There is a tool like webdeploy in apache tomcat to fix it?

Comment: Its difficult to be sure from what you say, but I would assume that you developed your project in something like `wamp\www\project` and did not create a Virtual Host for the project to run in. So now when you deploy to a folder that is actually the `DocumentRoot` folder all your relative links are wrong.

Comment: So you suggest me to create a Virtual Host? How?

Comment: Well this is how to [create Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) but this is not a magic bullet. Once you create a VHOST for your app to run in it will do just what your LIVE site does. But it will give you a correct environmant to make the required changes in before copying to LIVE again.